# Is there a way to stratify tableone in R by a continuous variable

Tags: r

I am analyzing a large dataset in R and in creating my TableOne i want to stratify the overall sample by presence of a variable. I am working with patients who have received a pulmonary hypertension measurement (continuous variable), but in my tableone i just want to compare patients who had the measurement vs those who did not.

Any help is appreciated. i know i have to specify the strata but i dont know how to do this for presence of a continuous measure vs. those who dont have the measure (AKA. their cells would be empty). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `group_by` with an `is.na` and `summarise` to find the summary statistics.

```
library(dplyr)

# data creation
set.seed(1724)

df <- mtcars
df[runif(nrow(df)) > 0.6,]$disp <- NA

# analysis

df %>%
  group_by(is.na(disp)) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  `is.na(disp)` Count
  <lgl>         <int>
1 FALSE            21
2 TRUE             11
```